# WPF MVVM DataGrid blank cells, define headers separately

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm writing a generic import tool for my company. The user is supposed to be able to specify file that contains rows/columns of data like a spreadsheet or tab- or comma-delimited values file. Loading the file is not an issue;  I am storing the column headers and the row data into separate lists, since I need them separated for the rest of the import logic.

I want to be able to display this data to the user after they load the import file. I figured a `DataGrid` would be my best bet.

Here's the xaml for the DataGrid I have:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          Height="150" />
```

This is part of a user control that is used as a static resource into a content control in the main window. The main window uses a view-model locator to set this view's data context.

However, when I populate Rows in the view model and include the headers as the first list in the collection, which is a `ObservableCollection<IList<string>>`, the headers and rows are blank, and the incorrect number of columns are generated.

**Question 1:** Why are the strings not showing in the cells?
**Question 2:** Is there a means to bind the loaded headers to the DataGrid without having to add them to the Rows collection first?

Thanks!

Comment: A list of lists?  Not sure a DG can accept this as a DC.  Normally a DG would be bound to a collection of MODELS, each model being the DataContext of each row, and the properties of the model would be bound to the cells in each column.  Besides, this would never work even if it did.  You cannot bind to a string in a collection and be able to update it (if that's your goal).  A binding can't substitute immutable instance A for immutable instance B in a List<T> at index 10.  That's just not how bindings work.

Comment: For binding columns, I'd start out with attempting something like a CustomDependencyProperty for DataGrid that takes a collection, and generates the DataGrid's columns based on that list. I did something similar with a regular Grid's RowCount and ColumnCount properties [here](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) that is probably similar if you want an example. Only problem with that, is your Header and BoundProperty would probably have to be named the same, unless you implemented a custom class that was expected for this DP.